# How to string together a few watch commands in npm?

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I have an npm start command that asks pug and stylus to watch files, and starts up http-server.

I'm a little amateur with bash. Should I be using `;`s or `&`s?

```
"start": "pug -w source/ --out target/ & stylus -w source/ --out target/ & sync-files -w source/ target/ & http-server target/",
```

My trouble here is that I want all these commands to keep running until I press `ctrl` + `c`, and then I want all of them to stop.

Comment: `&` attempts to launch command in background and continues with the next command without bothering about the termination of the command. While `;` terminates the commands in sequence.

Comment: I thought `;` does that, and `&` only runs if output of the previous command was successful?

Comment: `&&` checks for the Success Exit Code.

Comment: (I just reread that, got it, so ; would end each commands, so I'm doing it right with &, thanks!!!)